# How to modify css class using jinja2 macro

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Hi guys i'm learning flask and have a problem. I'm trying to modify a input form control class based on validation.

In the jinja2 template i have the following (i'm using render_field) have imported the macro:

```
{% from 'includes/_formhelpers.html' import render_field %}

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group input-group-alternative mb-3">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="ni ni-hat-3"></i></span>
              </div>
              {{ render_field(form.username, placeholder="Username",class="form-control") }}
            </div>
          </div>
```

And then in the macro file i have the following content:

```
{% macro render_field(field) %}
{{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
{% if field.errors %}
  {% for error in field.errors %}
      <input class="form-control is-invalid">
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
    {{ error }}
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

The problem is that the macro in rendering another input box

[image: Rendered form]

Generated HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
 <div class="input-group input-group-alternative mb-3">
         <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="ni ni-hat-3"></i></span>
         </div>

    <input class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" required="" type="text" value="pandazulweb">
    <input class="form-control is-invalid">
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Username already in use.
        </div>
</div>
```

I think it's something related to kwargs and how i'm passing the class to the template but i'm a noob with jinja2

Answer (score 0):

Unless I’m missing something, it looks like the second field is due to the ‘<input class=“form-control is-invalid”>’ which you’re including in the error condition of your macro.

**EDIT:** <s>In order to pass the class to a form field, you need to use ‘class_=“is-invalid”‘, not ‘class=‘. So just use that and remove the second input from your error case.</s>

**EDIT 2:** I think I see what the problem is. You need to put the first call to field() inside the macro’s error block, in the else block. So only if there is no error will it create the field with kwargs, etc.

Comment: Yes, that's right but what i need instead is set in the first <input class="form.control".... >  the class is-invalid.  And i don't figure out how to do it.

Comment: I’ve updated the answer, hopefully this will resolve your question.

Comment: Are you still seeing this problem?